# HTML move div next to text after click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm searching for a way to move a div-element which look like to bulletpoint next to a header text.
For example: if I click "Test 2" I want the bulletpoint move on the same height as the clicked text.
If I clcik "Test 1" I want it to move back.

Here is my tested JavaScript but it didn't moved.
I dont know if Javascript ist the best way to do it or should I try with CSS?

```
function moveBulletpoint(id) {
  var clickElem = document.getElementById(id);
  document.getElementById("bulletpoint").offsetTop = clickElem.offsetTop;
}
```

[Example Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgEzk.jpg)

Comment: please post the code that you have tried to achieve the above attached image

Comment: @ThinkCode is it possible to add some html sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using the [element.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) api.

While this example only moves the element, you could also animate it, etc.

```js
const firstItem = document.getElementById("firstItem");
const secondItem = document.getElementById("secondItem")
const elementToBeMoved = document.getElementById("handle")

const firstItemInitialTopPosition = firstItem.offsetTop;
elementToBeMoved.style.top = firstItemInitialTopPosition + 'px'

firstItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const itemTopPosition = firstItem.offsetTop;
  elementToBeMoved.style.top = itemTopPosition + 'px'
})

secondItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const itemTopPosition = secondItem.offsetTop;
  elementToBeMoved.style.top = itemTopPosition + 'px'
})
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

.handle-container {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
   

.handle-container div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6px
}

li { list-style: none}

h2 { cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 10px }
h2:hover {opacity: 0.6}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="handle-container">
    <div id="handle"></div>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <h2 id="firstItem">First item</h2>
      Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero.

    </li>
    <li>
      <h2 id="secondItem">Second item</h2>
      Now that we know who you are, I know who I am. I'm not a mistake! It all makes sense! In a comic, you know how you can tell who the arch-villain's going to be? He's the exact opposite of the hero. And most times they're friends, like you and me! I should've

    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an accordion and it can be achieved using Javascript.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>

<p class="accordion">Section 1</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p class="accordion">Section 2</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<p class="accordion">Section 3</p>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```